# ios - How to paginate results using Geofire with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, pagination, geofire

I have a `CollectionView` which displays items ordered by location, and I am trying to paginate them by a given amount (f.e 20 items).

I am using `Geofire` to order them by location, but the problem is that it doesn´t support queries limited by result count, so I can´t get a whole page without accesing all the ids.

I came up with the idea of geting on the first page all the item keys within the give location  ordered by location:

```
locationQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
    print("KEY: ", key, " and location: ", location.coordinate)
    itemKeys.append(key)
})

locationQuery?.observeReady {
    print("All item keys loaded. There are: ", itemKeys.count, " items in radius")
    locationQuery?.removeAllObservers()
    completion(itemKeys) //itemKeys.count would be the number of cells in the collectionView
}
```

Then save them, and in each page the next (pageAmount) of the itemKeys is retrieved and queried using Firebase `rererence.child(itemKeyInArray)`.

My main concern about this is that if I have a very big set of items in database, how efficient would it be iterating (and sorting) through all the keys.

Another approach was starting with a small radius, and increasing it in each page until the limit, and despite it seems more efficient I would still need the total number of items within the radius (to calculate the number of cells in the `CollectionView`)

Which would it be the proper approach to paginate the results by location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do pagination on Geofire at the moment. The most common approach I've seen is to do a few progressively wider range queries, so that the nearby items show up first, as you also tried already. You can also get all the keys for a wider range, and then order them on distance yourself to do the pagination. That way you only need to retrieve the details for a subset of the keys. Both approaches are valid, neither is objectively better than the other.

Also see:

- [Can I apply pagination on GeoFire Query to reduce load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912772/can-i-apply-pagination-on-geofire-query-to-reduce-load-time)
- [Lazy Loading Geofire results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508399/lazy-loading-geofire-results)
- Results for [GeoFire order by distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=geofire+order+by+distance)
- Results for [GeoFire pagination](https://www.google.com/search?q=geofire+pagination)

Comment: you answered this question in 2019, has there been any updates to paginate on GeoFire?

Comment: No. Pagination is inherently hard to  combine with geohash based queries.